# update height of element after a resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, height

How can i know the height of an element after a resize event? I use the function .height() of jQuery and i have a timer of 500ms before use my resize function but the function .height() still return the height before the resize.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    window.clearTimeout(timerResize);
    timerResize = setTimeout(recalculateAll, 1000);
});

function recalculateAll() {
    console.log('resize');
    setOpenClose('.auteurs .block');
}

function setOpenClose(target) {
    $(target).each(function() {
        $(this).data('height', $(this).height());
        $(this).height($(this).height() - ($(this).find('p').height() + 45));
    });
    sameHeights(target);
}

function sameHeights(target, locus) {
    if (locus === undefined) {
        locus = target;
    }
    var heightMax = 1;
    $(target).each(function() {
        if ($(this).height() > heightMax) {
            heightMax = $(this).height();
        }
    });
    $(target).each(function() {
        $(this).height(heightMax);
    });
}
```

Hoping my question is understandable because of my approximate english, and the fact i'm new in development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to call the retrieve the height of the element in the resize callback.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var itemHeight = $('.item').height();
});
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/cvwf0pra/

Comment: It's functional so thanks and if in dont find better i will use it, but i dont like to rewrite my functions in the callback just for this, i will see the callback proprety to finding a way to spread the new value of the proprety.